# Switch existing windows install in multiboot environment to independent?

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, bootloader

I have two physical drives. The new drive I installed another copy of windows on but the old drive contains the bootloader. If I disconnect the old drive how can I make the new drive boot independently? I don't think making it the first startup drive in my BIOS will be enough.

Secondly, if I want this new drive to be the default and I have an existing windows install on another drive, do I just run bootrec to select it and a boot menu will then show on startup?